# Need Troubleshooting help regarding Arduino Uno & HC-06 Bluetooth connection problem

Tags: arduino

I just bought Arduino Uno and HC-06, I hooked up the connections:

- 5V Bluetooth → 5V Arduino
- GND Bluetooth → GND Arduino
- TDX Bluetooth → RX →1
- RDX bluetooth → TX → 0

Here are the pictures:

[image: HC-06]
[image: Arduino]

My problem is that I cannot seem to search for the Bluetooth connection on my Laptop or on my phone.
Is there something wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1):

The R and T in "Rx" and "Tx" stand for "Receiver" and "Transmitter".

So the Transmitter from one device should be connected to the receiver of the other device. Thus:

1. Arduino Uno Rx -> HC-06 Tx
2. Arduino Uno Tx -> HC-06 Rx

EDIT:

Thanks to the pictures that I can now see, what are the values of the resistors on the Arduino Tx pin? 2.2k I think, but I cannot see very well.

In idle mode, both Tx and Rx should be high (5V). Can you verify this with a multimeter? [This](http://www.exp-tech.de/service/datasheet/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products.pdf) pdf  (p.8) states that the Rx should be pulled high. I assume that is what you did with the resistors, but I am confused to why you have two resistors. Could you explain this please? Usually a simple 10k resistor to Vcc should be sufficient. Adding a resistor between the Arduino Tx and the cable will cause reflections because of the impedance change and affect the signal quality.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, bluetooth is properly connected to the arduino in the picture

Comment: I can't seem to find any bluetooth connection from my phone when i scan